# How do I customize dialog signal/slot in pyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a set of buttons, OK and Cancel

```
buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|
                                    QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
```

I want a dialogue prompt when we click on `Cancel`

```
self.connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL("rejected()"),
                            self, SLOT("reject()"))
    def reject(self):
        print 'hello'
        self.emit(SIGNAL("reject()"))
```

I am not sure what to emit. I don't want to just close the thing. I know how to create a `QMessageBox` when I press `X`. I want to do the prompt and closing in `reject`.

I hope it makes sense. Thanks.

---

For your information, when I press `X` to close the entire application, I have an overriden method

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', 'Are you sure to quit?', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

This override `self.close()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't emit anything. `QDialog` has a [`reject()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qdialog.html#reject) slot that sets the return code to `Rejected` and closes the dialog. You need to call that. You named your custom slot `reject` as well, thus overriding it. You can still call it like:

```
super(NameOfClass, self).reject()
```

or change your slot name to something else and use:

```
self.reject()
```

in there.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna overwrite the accept() function of your QDialog class.

For example:

```
def accept(self):
    if your_validation_userconfirmation_fct():
        self.done(QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's overwrite the accept() function.

```
def accept(self):
    if validation_ok():
        super().accept()
```